# How to run Visual Studio Markup Validation for all files in a project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I am renaming some tagPrefix for a web form application.

For example

```
    <add tagPrefix="dx" namespace="DevExpress.Web" assembly="DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"/>
```

Changed to

```
    <add tagPrefix="dxw" namespace="DevExpress.Web" assembly="DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"/>
```

The Markup Validation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f940516c(v=vs.110).aspx) only show me the warnings if I am currently editing a page.

[image: markup validation]

I need to check all the aspx and ascx files in my solution (a lot o files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a way to get Warnings to populate in the Error List without opening the file.  However you could use a trick to open up all the files.

**Open all effected files**

- Open Find and Replace (Ctrl + Shift + H)
- Set "Find what" to "dx:"
- Set "Replace with" to "dx:" *(this won't actually change the files because it is the same as the original text)*
- Set "Look in" to "Entire Solution"
- Select "Keep modified files open after Replace All
- Click "Replace All"

This will open up all files that use the tag prefix "dx" and subsequently populate any errors on those pages in the Error List.

**If you can't find the Error List:**

You can view warnings in the Error List window.  To open the Error List window press Ctrl + \ then press E

Note you may need to click on the Errors or Warnings headers to toggle their visibility.

You may also need to set the filter for the error list.

[image]

Comment: I know, thanks. The question is how to run the validator for all the files in the solution. If you have the apsx page closed no warning is displayed in the Error List Window.

Comment: That's odd.  I'm running Visual Studio Premium 2013 and it shows me warnings for files that are not currently open.  Is your error list filter set to Current Project?

Comment: That is the tricky part: your Visual Studio remembers the errors because you have previously opened the page. Try to close the document that cause all the Warnings, then do a "Clean Solution". Now all the Warnings are gone; that is my problem: I have to open all the files again.

Comment: Okay, I'm able to duplicate the issue now. I haven't found a way to run validation without opening all files, but I updated my answer to include a trick for opening all effected files.

Comment: Sir you are a scholar and a gentleman. Your solution show some MacGyver level of thinkering!